# Personal School Course Scheduler

Tags: python, csv, search

A good friend of mine had the challenge of trying to build a schedule using all available times and classes through a spreadsheet... by hand. He asked me if I could build a program to generate valid schedules, and with search algorithms being one of my favorite things to do, I accepted the task.

At first glance through my research, I believed this to be an Interval Scheduling problem; however, since the courses have unique timespans on multiple days, I needed a better way to represent my data. Ultimately I constructed a graph where the vertices are the sections of a class and the neighbors are compatible sections. This allowed me to use a DFS-like algorithm to find schedules.

I have never asked for a code review since I am yet to take CS classes, but I would like to know where I stand with my organization, usage of data structures, and general approaches. One thing I also want an opinion on is commenting, something I *rarely* do and one day it will come back to haunt me. This is actually the first time I wrote docstrings, which I hope you will find useful in understanding the code.

Anyways, I exported a spreadsheet of the valid courses into a .csv file. Below is the Python code I wrote to parse the file and generate schedules:

**scheduler.py**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from enum import Enum

class Days(Enum):
    """
    Shorthand for retrieving days by name or value
    """
    Monday = 0
    Tuesday = 1
    Wednesday = 2
    Thursday = 3
    Friday = 4

class Graph:
    """
    A simple graph which contains all vertices and their edges;
    in this case, the class and other compatible classes

    :param vertices: A number representing the amount of classes
    """
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)

    def add_edge(self, u, v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)

class Section:
    """
    Used to manage different sections of a class
    Includes all times and days for a particular section

    :param section_str: A string used to parse the times at which the class meets
                        Includes weekday, start time, and end time
                        Format as follows: Monday,7:00,9:30/Tuesday,3:30,5:30/Wednesday,5:30,6:50
    :param class_name: The name used to refer to the class (course)
    :param preferred: Preferred classes will be weighted more heavily in the search
    :param required: Search will force this class to be in the schedule
    """
    def __init__(self, section_str, class_name='Constraint', preferred=False, required=False):
        self.name = class_name
        self.preferred = preferred
        self.required = required
        self.days = []
        for course in section_str.rstrip('/').split('/'):
            d = {}
            data = course.split(',')
            day_mins = Days[data[0]].value * (60 * 24)
            d['start_time'] = self.get_time_mins(data[1]) + day_mins
            d['end_time'] = self.get_time_mins(data[2]) + day_mins
            self.days.append(d)

    """
    Parses a time into minutes since Monday at 00:00 by assuming no class starts before 7:00am

    :param time_str: A string containing time in hh:mm

    :returns: Number of minutes since Monday 00:00
    """
    @staticmethod
    def get_time_mins(time_str):
        time = time_str.split(':')
        h = int(time[0])
        if h < 7:
            h += 12
        return 60 * h + int(time[1])

    """
    A (messy) method used to display the section in a readable format

    :param start_num: minutes from Monday 00:00 until the class starts
    :param end_num: minutes from Monday 00:00 until the class ends

    :returns: A string representing the timespan
    """
    @staticmethod
    def time_from_mins(start_num, end_num):
        # 1440 is the number of minutes in one day (60 * 24)
        # This is probably the least clean part of the code?
        day = Days(start_num // 1440).name
        start_hour = (start_num // 60) % 24
        start_min = (start_num % 1440) - (start_hour * 60)
        start_min = '00' if start_min == 0 else start_min
        start_format = 'am'
        end_hour = (end_num // 60) % 24
        end_min = (end_num % 1440) - (end_hour * 60)
        end_min = '00' if end_min == 0 else end_min
        end_format = 'am'
        if start_hour > 12:
            start_hour -= 12
            start_format = 'pm'
        time = f'{day} {start_hour}:{start_min}{start_format} => '
        if end_hour > 12:
            end_hour -= 12
            end_format = 'pm'
        time += f'{end_hour}:{end_min}{end_format}'
        return time

    """
    Checks to see if two time ranges overlap each other

    :param other: Another section object to compare

    :returns: boolean of whether the sections overlap
    """
    def is_overlapping(self, other):
        for range_1 in self.days:
            for range_2 in other.days:
                if range_1['end_time'] > range_2['start_time'] and range_2['end_time'] > range_1['start_time']:
                    return True
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        strs = []
        for day in self.days:
            strs.append(self.time_from_mins(day['start_time'], day['end_time']))
        return '\n'.join(strs)

class Scheduler:
    """
    This class powers the actual search for the schedule
    It makes sure to fill all requirements and uses a
    search algorithm to find optimal schedules

    :param graph: Instance of a Graph object
    :param num_courses: A constraint on the number of courses that the schedule should have
    :param num_required: A number to keep track of the amount of required classes
    """
    def __init__(self, graph, num_courses=5, num_required=1):
        self.graph = graph.graph
        self.paths = []
        self.num_courses = num_courses
        self.num_required = num_required
        self.schedule_num = 1

    """
    A recursive search algorithm to create schedules
    Nodes are Section objects, with their neighbors being compatible courses

    :param u: The starting node in the search
    :param visited: A boolean list to keep track of visited nodes
    :param path: List passed through recursion to keep track of the path

    :returns: None (modifies object properties for use in __repr__ below)
    """
    def search(self, u, visited, path):
        num_courses = self.num_courses
        visited[u] = True
        path.append(u)

        if len(self.paths) > 1000:
            return
        if len(path) == num_courses and len([x for x in path if x.required is True]) == self.num_required:
            self.paths.append(list(path))
        else:
            for section in self.graph[u]:
                if visited[section] == False and not any((x.is_overlapping(section) or (x.name == section.name)) for x in path):
                    self.search(section, visited, path)
        path.pop()
        visited[u] = False

    def __repr__(self):
        out = ''
        for section in self.paths[self.schedule_num - 1]:
            out += f'{section.name}\n{"=" * len(section.name)}\n{repr(section)}\n\n'
        return out

def main():
    """
    Setup all data exported into a .csv file, and prepare it for search
    """
    data = {}
    # Parse csv file into raw data
    with open('classes.csv') as csvfile:
        csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')
        class_names = []
        for j, row in enumerate(csv_data):
            for i, item in enumerate(row):
                if j == 0:
                    if i % 3 == 0: # I believe there is a better way to read by columns
                        name = item.strip('*')
                        class_names.append(name)
                        # Preferred classes are labelled with one asterisk, required with two
                        preferred = item.count('*') == 1
                        required = item.count('*') == 2
                        data[name] = {
                            'sections_raw': [],
                            'sections': [],
                            'preferred': preferred,
                            'required': required
                        }
                else:
                    class_index = i // 3
                    data_ = data[class_names[class_index]]
                    data_['sections_raw'].append(item)

    # Create Section objects which can be compared for overlaps
    for _class in data: # Personally class is more natural for me than course or lecture, but I could replace it
        sections_raw = data[_class]['sections_raw']
        sections = []
        cur_str = ''
        # Section strings are always in groups of three (class name, start time, end time)
        for i in range(0, len(sections_raw), 3):
            if sections_raw[i] != '':
                for x in range(3):
                    cur_str += sections_raw[i + x] + ','
                cur_str += '/'
            else:
                if cur_str != '':
                    sections.append(Section(cur_str, _class, data[_class]['preferred'], data[_class]['required']))
                    cur_str = ''
        else:
            if cur_str != '':
                sections.append(Section(cur_str, _class, data[_class]['preferred'], data[_class]['required']))
                cur_str = ''
        data[_class]['sections'] = sections

    # A friend asked me to prevent the scheduler from joining classes at specific times
    # I used my Section object as a constraint through the is_overlapping method
    constraint = Section('Monday,4:00,6:00/' +
            'Tuesday,7:00,9:30/Tuesday,3:30,5:30/' +
            'Wednesday,4:00,6:00/' +
            'Thursday,7:00,9:30/Thursday,3:30,5:30/' +
            'Friday,7:00,10:00')
    section_data = []
    # Here we extract the compatible courses given the constraint
    for x in data.values():
        for s in x['sections']:
            if not s.is_overlapping(constraint):
                section_data.append(s)

    graph = Graph(len(section_data))
    for section in section_data:
        graph.graph[section] = []
    start = None

    # Now we populate the graph, not allowing any incompatible edges
    for section in section_data:
        if start is None:
            start = section
        for vertex in graph.graph:
            if not section.is_overlapping(vertex) and section.name != vertex.name:
                graph.add_edge(vertex, section)
    scheduler = Scheduler(graph)
    visited = defaultdict(bool)
    scheduler.search(u=start, visited=visited, path=[]) # We use our search algorithm with courses as nodes
    # The scheduler doesn't actually weight the preferred classes, so we sort all our valid schedules using
    # the lambda function and reverse the order to show schedules with preferred classes first
    scheduler.paths = sorted(scheduler.paths, key=
        lambda path: (len([p for p in path if p.preferred])),
        reverse=True)
    return scheduler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The scheduler object is created, and now we need a way for the user to view one of their schedules
    scheduler = main()
    n = int(input(f'There are {len(scheduler.paths)} found.\nWhich schedule would you like to see?\n#: '))
    if not 1 <= n <= len(scheduler.paths):
        print(f'Enter a number between 1-{scheduler.paths}.')
    else:
        scheduler.schedule_num = n
        print(scheduler)
```

The .csv file is generated from a spreadsheet that uses the following layout (visualizing it will help with understanding how I parse it):

[image: Spreadsheet with class data]

**classes.csv**

```
SPAN 201,Start,End,POLS 110*,Start,End,ENVS 130,Start,End,ACT 210,Start,End,FSEM**,Start,End,QTM 100*,Start,End
Tuesday,9:00,9:50,Tuesday,1:00,2:15,Tuesday,11:30,12:45,Monday,1:00,2:15,Tuesday,10:00,11:15,Monday,4:00,5:15
Thursday,9:00,9:50,Thursday,1:00,2:15,Thursday,11:30,12:45,Wednesday,1:00,2:15,Thursday,10:00,11:15,Wednesday,4:00,5:15
Friday,9:00,9:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Friday,9:00,9:50
,,,,,,,,,Monday,2:30,3:45,Monday,1:00,2:15,,,
Tuesday,10:00,10:50,,,,,,,Wednesday,2:30,3:45,Wednesday,1:00,2:15,Monday,4:00,5:15
Thursday,10:00,10:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Wednesday,4:00,5:15
Friday,10:00,10:50,,,,,,,Monday,4:00,5:15,Monday,10:00,10:50,Friday,11:00,11:50
,,,,,,,,,Wednesday,4:00,5:15,Wednesday,10:00,10:50,,,
Tuesday,12:00,12:50,,,,,,,,,,Friday,10:00,10:50,Monday,4:00,5:15
Thursday,12:00,12:50,,,,,,,Tuesday,8:30,9:45,,,,Wednesday,4:00,5:15
Friday,12:00,12:50,,,,,,,Thursday,8:30,9:45,,,,Friday,1:00,1:50
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Tuesday,1:00,1:50,,,,,,,Tuesday,10:00,11:15,,,,Tuesday,8:30,9:45
Thursday,1:00,1:50,,,,,,,Thursday,10:00,11:15,,,,Thursday,8:30,9:45
Friday,1:00,1:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Friday,10:00,10:50
,,,,,,,,,Tuesday,1:00,2:15,,,,,,
Tuesday,2:00,2:50,,,,,,,Thursday,1:00,2:15,,,,Tuesday,8:30,9:45
Thursday,2:00,2:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Thursday,8:30,9:45
Friday,2:00,2:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Friday,12:00,12:50
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Tuesday,3:00,3:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Tuesday,8:30,9:45
Thursday,3:00,3:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Thursday,8:30,9:45
Friday,3:00,3:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Friday,2:00,2:50
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Monday,10:00,10:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Tuesday,10:00,11:15
Wednesday,10:00,10:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Thursday,10:00,11:15
Friday,10:00,10:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Friday,11:00,11:50
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Monday,9:00,9:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Tuesday,10:00,11:15
Wednesday,9:00,9:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Thursday,10:00,11:15
Friday,9:00,9:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Friday,1:00,1:50
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Monday,2:00,2:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Monday,2:30,3:45
Wednesday,2:00,2:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Wednesday,2:30,3:45
Friday,2:00,2:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Friday,10:00,10:50
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Monday,3:00,3:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Monday,2:30,3:45
Wednesday,3:00,3:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Wednesday,2:30,3:45
Friday,3:00,3:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,Friday,2:00,2:50
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Monday,4:00,4:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Wednesday,4:00,4:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Friday,4:00,4:50,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Is there any reason for putting the docstrings above methods and not inside 'em? Looks really weird this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing is sure, there's too much logic going on in your main. your main should be clean, i.e. presenting only functions or methods and minimal logic, as, at a glance we can figure out what's going on when the main function is called

the blocks of code handle way too much related logics, break them up!